# php artisan schedule:run => No scheduled commands are ready to run

Tags: laravel, schedule, laravel-artisan

Laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log

```
[2020-04-08 10:41:01] staging.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at /home/u8614269/laravel/fti-presensi/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:246)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/u8614269/laravel/fti-presensi/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(246): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/u8614269/...', 246, Array)
#1 /home/u8614269/laravel/fti-presensi/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1060): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput->getFirstArgument()
#2 /home/u8614269/laravel/fti-presensi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(84): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->getCommandName(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput))
#3 /home/u8614269/laravel/fti-presensi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/u8614269/laravel/fti-presensi/artisan(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output like this :

```
Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php-cgi' 'artisan' command:your-command > '/dev/null' 2>&1
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.26
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Perhaps the problem is `/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php-cgi`

If you use Shared Hosting that use PHP Selector, this cron script works for me...

```
* * * * * /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php -q -d register_argc_argv=1 /laravel_app_path/artisan schedule:run >> /home/schedule.log 2>&1 &
```

Note : php72 is your php version. -d register_argc_argv=1 it to prevent overlapping. /home/schedule.log is optional. 2>&1 & is timestamp.